# Inserting new values based on certain condition

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm creating a new version of a table that adds 3 new columns. Here is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO  test_db.new_item  
SELECT A.*,'I','2010-02-01','9999-12-31' FROM db.item A WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'Y'
SELECT B.*,'U','2010-02-01',(CAST(LAST_UPD_TS AS DATE) - 1) FROM db.item B WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'N'
SELECT C.*,'D',CAST(LAST_UPD_TS AS DATE),'9999-12-31' FROM db.item C WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'N';
```

I created the new table with the same columns as the old one plus the 3 new columns I want. This insert is a one time only query to convert the existing data to the format I need it in. What I need to do is check whether `ACTV_FLG` is `Y` and insert certain values and check whether `ACTV_FLG` is `N` and insert two rows with different values to keep a history of the data. In that specific case to preserve the original row, then make a copy showing it's current state of deletion.

When I try to UNION it errors out. What other way could I combine these select statements?

Comment: i assume you are inserting more columns than there are in the new_item table.

Comment: No, the new_item table has all the new columns I need, but those columns are NOT NULL so I need to fill them with data.

Comment: what is the exact error message you get? column values being of a different data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get when you try to UNION is probably a `3654. Corresponding select-list expressions are incompatible`.

You try to mix Varchars and Dates, `'2010-02-01'` may look like a DATE but it's a VARCHAR. Use a date literal instead: `DATE '2010-02-01'`

```
INSERT INTO  test_db.new_item  
SELECT A.*,'I',DATE '2010-02-01', DATE '9999-12-31' 
FROM db.item A WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT B.*,'U',DATE '2010-02-01',(CAST(LAST_UPD_TS AS DATE) - 1) 
FROM db.item B WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT C.*,'D',CAST(LAST_UPD_TS AS DATE),DATE '9999-12-31' 
FROM db.item C WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'N';
```

But you might keep your existing three Inserts and run them as a Multi-Statement-Request, which is a single transaction in a Teradata mode session. In SQL Assistant it's simply pressing `F9` instead of `F5`  (should be similar in Teradata Studio) and in BTEQ it's based on the positon of the semicolin (if a new command starts on the same line after the semicolon it's part of the previous command):

```
SELECT A.*,'I',DATE '2010-02-01', DATE '9999-12-31' 
FROM db.item A WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'Y'
;INSERT INTO  test_db.new_item  
SELECT B.*,'U',DATE '2010-02-01',(CAST(LAST_UPD_TS AS DATE) - 1) 
FROM db.item B WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'N'
;INSERT INTO  test_db.new_item  
SELECT C.*,'D',CAST(LAST_UPD_TS AS DATE),DATE '9999-12-31' 
FROM db.item C WHERE ACTV_FLG = 'N'
;
```